# Assigning a variable based on conditional expressions

Tags: python

I am relatively new to programming and I would like to know if I am implementing the following code in a good way:

```
class Gene:
    def __init__(self, gene_symbol, gene_id):
        self.gene_symbol = gene_symbol
        self.gene_id = gene_id

        if is_valid_refseq(gene_id):
            self.gene_id_type = REFSEQ

        elif is_valid_ensembl_gene(gene_id):
            self.gene_id_type = ENSEMBL_GENE

        elif is_valid_ensembl_transcript(gene_id):
            self.gene_id_type = ENSEMBL_TRANSCRIPT

        else:
            raise InvalidGeneIDError
```

Assume `gene_id` and `gene_id_type` are strings. Is there a smarter way to condense the if-elif statements here (Especially if I decide to add more of these conditions)? I'm thinking there might be, but would that make the code less readable? As I move forward, I want to develop good coding habits/style and discover some handy tools/tricks Python along the way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think this is about as clean as you can make this code.

Comment: This code makes sense if either (a) refseq, emsembl_gene and ensembl_transcript are mutually exclusive categories,  or (b) refseq is a subset or special case of ensembl_gene, which is in turn a subset or special case of ensembl_transcript.     It doesn't work if the hierarchy goes the other way (e.g. if all ensembl_transcript genes are also refseq genes). As regards style, there's nothing wrong with it and I agree with Robert that this is about as readable as you could make it.

Comment: Note that this is really the place to ask about attempted but unsolved programming problems, not really "is my code OK?" type questions. You may want http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For the purposes of my implementation, assume that refseq, ensembl_gene, and ensembl_transcript are all mutually exclusive.

Comment: @jez FYI, rule #1 on [codereview.se], is that the code works as intended.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a loop with a `break` statement. The `else` clause remains exactly the same:

```
# somewhere outside __init__()
checks = [is_valid_refseq, is_valid_ensembl_gene, is_valid_ensembl_transcript]
idtypes = [REFSEQ, ENSEMBL_GENE, ENSEMBL_TRANSCRIPT]

# in __init__()
for check, value in zip(checks, idtypes):
    if check(gene_id):
        self.gene_id_type = value
        break
else:
    raise InvalidGeneIDError
```

You can also use a single dictionary instead of two lists, but that will not guarantee the order of checks. In case if only one check can be successful for any `gene_id`, using a dict would be nicer:

```
checks = {REFSEQ: is_valid_refreq, ENSEMBL_GENE: is_valid_ensembl_gene,
          ENSEMBL_TRANSCRIPT: is_valid_ensembl_transcript}
for value, check in checks.items():
    if check(gene_id):
        self.gene_id_type = value
        break
else:
    raise InvalidGeneIDError
```